# Postgres UNACCENT for character with more than 1 diacritic

Tags: postgresql, diacritics, unaccent

The `UNACCENT` function can strip diacritics off characters. However, in my case, it can only strip characters with 1 diacritic, for e.g.

- Thành
- Supermän
- äää

For characters with more than 1 diacritics, `UNACCENT` does nothing, for e.g.

- Hồ
- ầ
- phố

Is there a way to let Postgres strip the accents from these characters?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL's `unaccent` module does not use Unicode normalization, but only a simple search-and-replace dictionary. The default dictionary, [`unaccent.rules`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/unaccent/unaccent.rules), does not contain these Vietnamese characters, thus nothing is done.

You could create your own unaccent dictionary though. [As explained in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/unaccent.html):

1. Create a text file `vietnamese.rules` with content like

   ```
   ầ  a
   Ầ  A
   ồ  o
   Ồ  O
   ```
2. Move `vietnamese.rules` into the folder `$SHAREDIR/tsearch_data/` (usually `/usr/share/postgresql/tsearch_data`)
3. Run the function as

   ```
   SELECT unaccent('vietnamese', 'Hồ ầ phố');
   --              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ```

Comment: I was afraid to create my own rule since I don't have access to the DB computer, but I guess there is no avoiding it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I got this error
`
ERROR:  text search dictionary "vietnamese" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT unaccent('vietnamese', 'Hồ ầ phố');
`

Comment: @Homnomnomnom... Just submitted an edit addressing your problem. You need to run the appropriate `CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY` command.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new function to do `unaccent` job like below:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.vietnamese_unaccent(text)
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    input_string text := $1;
BEGIN

input_string := translate(input_string, 'áàãạảAÁÀÃẠẢăắằẵặẳĂẮẰẴẶẲâầấẫậẩÂẤẦẪẬẨ', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
input_string := translate(input_string, 'éèẽẹẻEÉÈẼẸẺêếềễệểÊẾỀỄỆỂ', 'eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee');
input_string := translate(input_string, 'íìĩịỉIÍÌĨỊỈ', 'iiiiiiiiiii');
input_string := translate(input_string, 'óòõọỏOÓÒÕỌỎôốồỗộổÔỐỒỖỘỔơớờỡợởƠỚỜỠỢỞ', 'ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo');
input_string := translate(input_string, 'úùũụủUÚÙŨỤỦưứừữựửƯỨỪỮỰỬ', 'uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu');
input_string := translate(input_string, 'ýỳỹỵỷYÝỲỸỴỶ', 'yyyyyyyyyyy');
input_string := translate(input_string, 'dđĐD', 'dddd');

return input_string;
END;
$function$
```

It's works for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you use from version 13 onwards, the Postgresql already support that function here:

```
select normalize('hồ, phố, ầ', NFC) → 'ho, pho, a' -- NFC (the default), NFD, NFKC, or NFKD.
```

Document: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html